# How do I stop Linux from scanning for partitions on a hard drive?

Tags: linux-kernel, data-recovery, badblocks

Background:

I'm trying to recover data from a dying SATA hard drive.  When the drive reads a bad sector, it locks up until the system is power cycled.  Linux (Debian) correctly reads the partition layout at boot time, so SOME of the sectors on the drive are still good - the problem is that partition autodetect also reads some of the bad sectors, so I wind up unable to get at the good sectors.

Detecting partitions at boot time is fine - the recovery system's boot drive is PATA; renaming ahci.ko enables me to boot without initializing the SATA controller at all until I manually insmod it.  But insmodding ahci.ko autodetects the partitions and locks me out of the drive again.

What I want to do is either turn off partition autodetect at run time or turn off partition autodetect for all ahci drives, but I'm not sure how to do either of those.  I have a distinct suspicion that this will require kernel modding, but I'm not sure where in the kernel to start.